# MySQL JOIN+WHERE gives no results

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause, multiple-tables

I create DB (MySQL 5.5, Ubuntu 14.04) where I want to search companies by divisions (that company is belonging to) and keywords. Let's say we have tables -

```
company (c_id,c_name)   
-------------------------------   
1   'A-Z hair'   
2   'My Coffee'   
3   'Boom Disco'   
4   'Go Cinema'   

keywords (c_fk , keyword)   
-----------------   
1  'haircut'   
1  'pruning'   
1  'coloring'   
2  'coffee'   
2  'tea'   
2  'free wifi'   

division( d_id , d_name)   
---------------   
1   'shop'   
2   'service'   
3   'manufacturing'   
4   'engineering'    
5   'food'  
6   'entertainment'  

comp_div ( c_fk , d_fk )  
-----------------------   
1   2   
2   5   
2   2   
4   6
```

( .._fk columns are foreign key connections)
I need a select with several optional criteria that returns companies where

(company belongs to specific division OR division doesn't matter)  AND
(some company's keyword is 'something'  OR keywords doesn't matter)

Here is the sqlfiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd0b6/7). Unfortunately there is some bug and Mysql 5.5 mode is not working, so I test on 5.6

I start compiling my search query with creating following JOIN

```
SELECT c_id,c_name,d_fk,keyword FROM company   
LEFT JOIN comp_div ON c_id=comp_div.c_fk  
LEFT JOIN keywords ON c_id=keywords.c_fk
```

which works as expected and gives all rows with all companies * divisions * keywords

Then I want to refine results with additional WHERE, so I add e.g.
WHERE keyword='something'. Of course, there is issue with NULL comparison so WHERE fails and the query gives no results. I intend to extend search request for case where keyword and/or division parameter is present but also not present. So my idea is to have something like this -

```
SELECT c_id,c_name,d_fk,keyword FROM company   
LEFT JOIN comp_div ON c_id=comp_div.c_fk  
LEFT JOIN keywords ON c_id=keywords.c_fk  
WHERE (''=keyword OR keyword LIKE somethin%) AND  
(comp_div.d_fk=<division_fk> OR comp_div.d_fk = 0)
```

I desperately try all methods e.g.
1. moving condition to ON ..

```
SELECT c_id,c_name,d_fk,keyword FROM company      
LEFT JOIN comp_div ON c_id=comp_div.c_fk    
LEFT JOIN keywords ON (c_id=keywords.c_fk) AND (keyword='something')
```

which works strange way as it gives results all with null keyword

2.applying WHERE on derived table without WHERE + IFNULL/COALESCE

```
SELECT c_id,c_name,d_fk,keyword FROM(    
SELECT c_id,c_name,d_fk,keyword FROM company     
LEFT JOIN comp_div ON c_id=comp_div.c_fk   
LEFT JOIN keywords ON c_id=keywords.c_fk) dt   
WHERE COALESCE(dt.keyword,'')='something'
```

which is probably stupid and returns no results.

Please advice best practices to do the job. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share and **sql fiddle** with some sample data? Also mention your expected output in tabular form.

Comment: I added sample tables and sqlfiddle to my original post

Answer (score 0):

After hour of trials and study next solution is found - my intention originally was to perform 2 selects, one for each criteria (division, keyword) and then do intersect of tables. As INTERSECT is not supported in MySQL, it can be simulated by IN operator and subquery like here -

```
SELECT c_id,c_name FROM company
LEFT JOIN keywords K ON c_id=K.c_fk AND K.keyword LIKE @keyword
WHERE (K.c_fk IS NOT NULL OR @keyword='') AND
c_id IN (
SELECT c_id FROM company
LEFT JOIN comp_div D ON c_id=D.c_fk AND D.d_fk = @division   
WHERE D.c_fk IS NOT NULL OR @division=-1)
GROUP BY c_id
```

Trick resides in figuring out what happens with LEFT JOIN result when valid criteria is applied and when criteria is omitted (@keyword=''). In first case (@keyword<>'') we need to remove all rows that have NULLs on right side (those which dont match ) and its done by IS NOT NULL clause.
In latter case we want all rows, no matter what keywords are. Thats ensured by WHERE TRUE. 
Second SELECT is identical in structure, it just uses division id as criteria (-1 for don't care)
Using more IN constructions any necessary number of criterias can be applied.